# Is it possible to switch a computer between two hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, multi-boot

So I was wondering if I could remove all hard drives from my computer, plug in a brand new hard drive, then install a new OS on it. I know I could just dual boot from a partitioned disk but want to do this to effectively have two computers (one Windows, one Linux). Would I then be able to switch back and forth between the two 'systems' while the computer is powered off? I'm not sure if I'm asking this right so clarification questions are welcomed.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: With totally separate hard drives, you could use the BIOS at startup to manually select which to boot from (no need to plug and unplug drives).  However, if one or more of the OSes will be Linux,  it will include GRUB, which will create a boot menu from which you can choose which OS to boot from.  They can be on separate drives and/or partitions of the same drive.  None of these options require powering off, just restart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible - I just did that the other day: The BIOS of a PC is capable of letting the HDDs to be exchanged (if the PC is off). As most BIOSes today have HDD auto-detection enabled, this also can be done easily. Usually, there is nothing stored in the BIOS itself, which binds the other hardware of a PC to a single HDD.

Please note, however, that there are newer PCs/BIOSes, which have some check capabilities, if an HDD was exchanged: Sometimes they hide themselves as "Anti Virus detection". Moreover, there may be special cases with the new [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) BIOSes, which also may store some part of the startup routine on a HDD. If that one is missing, you might run into trouble. However, I personally, would consider this as an edge case -- and should be easy to fix by just using the old disk again.

Why don't you just try it out? If you fail to install the Operating System on the second disk, you simply may revert back to the first...

Answer (score 0):

Well in short you can have multiple bootable os's on a single hard drive via partitions.. Which a partition is basically like have two harddrives.. So multiple harddrives with different os's will work and be bootable as long as they have the right drivers.. I'm assuming you have say more then 3 hard drives like I do. Now per hard drive you can have multiple partitions.. So let's say I have a 1 Tb ssd and a 500gb HDD and a 500gb SSD.. I can load Windows and Linux on the 1 Tb SSD.. And also have a different Linux on a different hard drive... All work.. All boot.. But the different harddrives I would have to manually select which to boot In the bios.. And if the HD had multiple os's on it, it would then ask which to boot.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.